# Cant understand perror's message with mkdir

Tags: linux, mkdir, errno, strerror

I have a piece of code which creates a directory from a string, **cwd** here is a string giving the directory path. Unfortunately there was an error which didn't allow me to create the directory, so I used the ***perror()*** and ***strerror()*** functions like so, to get the symbolic name of the error.

```
struct stat st = {0};
if (stat(cwd, &st) == -1) {

    if(mkdir(cwd, 0700)==-1){
        int err=errno;
        perror("MKDIR ERROR");
        printf("%s \n",strerror(err));
    }

}
```

My problem is that *perror()* and *strerror()* give an error saying 'No such file or directory exists'. I looked up the man page of mkdir [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir), but the said error is not in the list of errors given on the man page.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does the parent directory (ie the directory where you're trying to put your new directory) exist?

Comment: And is cwd a valid path (valid in terms of allowed characters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the said error is not in the list of errors given on the man page

It clearly shows `ENOENT` which is exactly what you are seeing. Most likely one of the components of your path ("ancestors") does not exist.

Comment: I recommend against linux.die.net. I think a better alternative is http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html